# Duplicates in Criteria.list()

Tags: hibernate

```
public List<String> listOfChunks() {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Student.class);
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("id"));
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.sqlProjection("right(name,1) as lastChar", new String[]{"lastChar"}, new Type[]{ new StringType()}));
        return criteria.list();
    }
```

Above query is giving me last char of all the students name, how can i avoid duplicates in lastchar which I am getting in list() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Projections.distinct](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html#distinct(org.hibernate.criterion.Projection)) which creates a distinct projection from a projection

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Student.class);
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("id"));
        criteria.setProjection( Projections.distinct(
                                 Projections.sqlProjection("right(name,1) as lastChar"
                               , new String[]{"lastChar"}
                               , new Type[]{ new StringType()})));
        return criteria.list();
```